# How cancel previous request on ExpressJs

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, crud

I am beginner in backend development. Make NodeJs API on ExpressJs. I have get endpoint that send response after 5 seconds using setTimeout. But if a new request was sent before the old returned a response, i need to cancel old. Tryed make it using cleartimeout? but it doesn't help. ClearTimeout works when old response has been sent.

```
  async getUser(email, number) {
    let timeout;
    ...
    const wrapper = () => {
      clearTimeout(timeout);

      return new Promise(resolve => {

        timeout = setTimeout(() => {
          ...
          resolve(user);
        }, 5000);
      });
    };
    const result = wrapper();

    return await result;
```

How can i solve this problem? Or this makes on frontend side?